# How to get ip address of a server on Centos 7 in bash

Tags: bash, ip-address, centos7

Previously I used the following command in bash to find the main ip of my server

```
ipaddr=$(/sbin/ifconfig|grep inet|head -1|sed 's/\:/ /'|awk '{print $3}' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')
```

But in centos7 it no longer works since ifconfig isn't available and the command no longer works even if I install `ifconfig` using `yum install net-tools`

What is the equivalent command for centos 7

Thanks a lot

Comment: i think it's better to ask this question somewhere else like Superuser or Unix and Linux.

Comment: @Cryrus could you post the command as an answer ?

Comment: Is the output from `ip addr show` useful for you? You'll have to adjust the manner in which you parse it of course...

Answer (score 122):

You can use [hostname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) command :

```
ipaddr=$(hostname -I)
```

> `-i, --ip-address`:
>       Display the IP address(es) of the host. Note that this works only if the host name can be resolved.
>
> `-I, --all-ip-addresses`:
>       Display all network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network interfaces. The loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this option does not depend on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

Comment: For multiple interfaces (docker, flocker, etc) use echo $(hostname -I | cut -d" " -f 1)  The first one is the default one.

Comment: That -f 1 doesn't always work.  On my VM that gives me 127.0.0.1.  So I would have to use -f 2 to get the proper IP.  If there is also an IP v6 address then it's questionable again if it gets the right IP.

Comment: For use within docker, I use $(hostname -i) instead. It gives me only one IP

Comment: this also worked for me:  
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com. ;

Comment: the first IP is: 
ipaddr=$(hostname -I|awk '{print $1}')

Comment: This gets all the ip addresses.

Answer (score 36):

Ref: https://garbagevalue.com/blog/4-simle-ways-to-check-ip-adress-in-centos-7

---

I'm using CentOS 7 and command

`ip a`

is enough to do the job.

[image]

### Edit

Just slice out the IP address part from that test.

`ip a | grep 192`

Comment: have you got the sense of it?

Comment: A fairy came in my dreams to tell me this.

Comment: What package contains `ip`?

Answer (score 35):

Enter the command `ip addr` at the console

[image]

Answer (score 5):

hostname -I | awk ' {print $1}'

Answer (score 4):

Bit late however I use

```
curl -4 icanhazip.com
```

returns the server Primary IP address.

Answer (score 3):

```
SERVER_IP="$(ip addr show ens160 | grep 'inet ' | cut -f2 | awk '{ print $2}')"
```

replace ens160 with your interface name

Comment: I don't think the cut -f2 does anything in this command. The awk should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this - a riff on @maarten-vanlinthout's answer

```
ip  -f inet a show eth0| grep inet| awk '{ print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

Comment: There is nothing worse than down-voting an answer without giving reasons why.  Please, provide a reason and down-vote, or simply provide just the reason you have a problem with the answer.

Comment: This version does not work anymore one modern Linux distros since the device simply has a different name. eth0, eth1 etc is not used anymore - at least on Red Hat 8, newer Fedoras, Opensuse, ...

Answer (score 3):

You can run simple commands like

```
curl ifconfig.co

curl ifconfig.me

wget -qO - icanhazip.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, when you do not want to use external sources (or cannot), I would recommend:

```
DEVICE=$(ls -l /sys/class/net | awk '$NF~/pci0/ { print $(NF-2); exit }')
IPADDR=$(ip -br address show dev $DEVICE | awk '{print substr($3,1,index($3,"/")-1);}')
```

The first line gets the name of the first network device on the PCI bus, the second one gives you its IP address.

BTW `ps ... | grep ... | awk ...`
stinks. awk does not need grep.

Comment: That's the best one so far. Also, works on CentOS 8. But using more than one PCI card, it won't show IP address. Here's my version using only awk, and showing IP of all up interfaces `IPADDR=$(ip -br address show | awk '$2 == "UP" {print substr($3,1,index($3,"/")-1);}')`

Comment: My version was intended to yield the *first* card, that is what the first line takes care of. If that device is not up, you might end without IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the most reliable way to get the external server ip address would be to use an external service.

`ipaddr=$(curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/)`

Answer (score -2):

Run this command to show ip4 and ip6:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

Comment: The question explicitly says that `ifconfig` is no longer installed.